# How to include more than one file pattern in Mercurial command

Tags: mercurial

Mercurial 1.7.5 on Windows.

I have a few files I have modified, and want to split them into two commits.  To do so, I'm playing with the -I (or --include) option.  Docs state:

```
-I --include PATTERN [+]     include names matching the given patterns
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to include more than one pattern yet.  I've tried:

```
hg status -I C:\folderToSolution\Project1\**.cs C:\folderToSolution\Project3\**.cs
hg status -I C:\folderToSolution\Project1\**.cs +C:\folderToSolution\Project3\**.cs
```

(Using status to test my pattern before committing.)

What's the syntax for getting more than one pattern in the option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specify `-I` before each pattern

```
hg status -I C:\folderToSolution\Project1\**.cs -I C:\folderToSolution\Project3\**.cs
```

The `[+]` in the documentation means that the option can be specified more than once.